# Delete key on keyboard not working in extjs

Tags: forms, extjs

I have form created in extjs. In the textfield when I press the <kbd>delete</kbd> key on keyboard the content does not get deleted, whereas the <kbd>backspace</kbd> key is working fine. How to enable the <kbd>delete</kbd> key in extjs?

Answer (score 2):

The delete key should work just fine inside a textfield. There's probably some other code of yours that's stopping it from working.

Try the example code from [the documentation of textfield](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text) (I'm assuming you are using Ext 4). If it works, the problem is in your code. Figure out what are you doing differently. Comment out other parts of the code to see what might be causing it.

If the example code doesn't work, there's something else going wrong, but let's not go there before we have discarded the most likely cause - you own code.

Answer (score -1):

Use Event onkeydown or onkeypress in specific Input tag for which you want to execute delete.

Comment: It would be great if u could send me with example code in extjs.